# Why doesn't addition broadcast over tuples?

Tags: python, tuples

E.g., why can't I do:

```
(0,1) + (2,2)
```

and get:

```
(2,3)
```

as a result?

Comment: Simple answer - that is now how the + operator is defined for tuples

Comment: You could use `complex` instead.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/845758/1084416) to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845112/concise-vector-adding-in-python).

Comment: Because then you couldn't use `+` to concatenate the tuples.

Comment: Right... yeah I forgot about that.

I was actually trying to use subtraction of tuples with -, which just isn't defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `+` operator is used to make a new tuple that is the combination of two other tuples.  That is just how Python was designed.

To do what you want, you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
>>> t1 = (0,1)
>>> t2 = (2,2)
>>> tuple(x + y for x, y in zip(t1, t2))
(2, 3)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because of you add tow tuple and `+` operation for tuples concatenate them ! you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) functions for that :

```
>>> map(sum,zip((0,1),(2,2)))
[2, 3]
```

or use a generator :

```
>>> tuple(i+j for i,j in zip((0,1),(2,2)))
(2, 3)
```

and a better way with `operator.add`:

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> map(add,(0,1),(2,2))
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

'+' operator concatenate tuples . if you want to sum tuples item you can use:

```
tuple(sum(x) for x in zip((0,1),(2,2)))
```

or

```
tuple(map(sum,zip((0,1),(2,2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Python thinks of tuples as lists that are immutable, adding two tuples is just like adding two lists. So, just as adding two lists will concatenate them:

```
>>> [1, 2] + [3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

adding two tuples will also concatenate them:

```
>>> (1, 2) + (3, 4)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

You can create a new tuple that consists of the sum of each pair with a few of Python's built-in functions:

```
>>> tuple(map(sum, zip((0, 1), (2, 2))))
(2, 3)
```

This works by using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) on the two tuples to make a list of pairs:

```
>>> zip((0, 1), (2, 2))
[(0, 2), (1, 2)]
```

And using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to apply [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) on each element of that list, to get a list of sums:

```
>>> map(sum, zip((0, 1), (2, 2)))
[2, 3]
```

And, finally, using [`tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) to turn that from a list into a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Element-wise addition is a more specialized operation than concatenation. Fewer tuples could be added together: what would `('a','b') + (1,2,)` equal? 
Or `('a', 'b') + (1,2,3)` for that matter?

Since concatenation is arguably the more commonly desired operation, and importantly, well defined for all tuples, it makes sense that addition of tuples performs concatenation.