# How to add up 2 list elements to form a new list in python, by one shot?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, summary

I've defined 2 lists, n1 and n2:

```
In [1]: n1=[1,2,3]

In [2]: n2=[4,5,6]

In [3]: n1+n2
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

In [4]: n1+=n2

In [5]: n1
Out[5]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Well, what I expected to do is to get a new list:
n3=[5,7,9] as summary of each elements in n1 and n2.

I don't wish to write a for loop to do this routine job. 
Does python operator or library support a one-shot call to do this?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713321/element-wise-addition-of-2-lists-in-python), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845112/concise-vector-adding-in-python), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050824/add-sum-of-values-of-two-lists-into-new-list), and probably lots more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[x + y for x, y in zip(n1, n2)]
[n1[i] + n2[i] for i in range(len(n1))]
map(int.__add__, n1, n2)
```

Comment: This one is brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't wish to write a for loop to do this routine job. Does python operator or library support a one-shot call to do this?

Python does not support it natively, but you can use the library [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
import numpy as np

n1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
n2 = np.array([4, 5, 6])

n3 = n1 + n2
```

Alternatively, you can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
n3 = [x + y for x, y in zip(n1, n2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no one-shot command for that. Adding elements in two lists is not a common operation. You can't avoid a loop here.

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[a + b for a, b in zip(n1, n2)]
```

Alternatively, use  `numpy` arrays:

```
from numpy import array

n3 = array(n1) + array(n2)
```